# Mongoose findOne doesn't execute

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to get data but I don't know why it doesn't work

```
module.exports.addUser = function(firstName, lastName, userName, pwd, dob, email){      
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdb');

    var user = mongoose.model('user.profile', profile_schema);

    var newuser = new user();
    newuser.dob = dob;
    newuser.name.first = firstName;
    newuser.name.last = lastName;
    newuser.name.user = userName;
    newuser.pwd = crypto.createHash('md5').update(pwd).digest("hex");
    newuser.email = email;

    newuser.save(function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        // saved!
    });

    user.findOne({'email':'abc@gmail.com'}, function(err, data){
        console.log('here');
        console.log(data);
        console.log(err);
    });
    mongoose.disconnect();
};
```

I use this code to add user: `addUser('hii','heee','sss','123456','28/05/1991','abc@gmail.com');`

It's ok when the code adds data to database (no error, I checked database on console) but I can't get anything (no log is shown) even though I changed the condition

```
user.findOne({}, function(err, data){
            console.log('here');
            console.log(data);
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: What does your logging output, apart from 'here' ?

Comment: there's no 'here' or anything output on console. I don't know why.

Comment: Can you check that the code is getting executed? Add a console.log before and after the `findOne` block

Comment: everything is ok, except findOne function.  
`console.log('before');

  user.findOne({'email':'abc@gmail.com'}, function(err, data){
   console.log('here');
   console.log(data);
   console.log(err);
  });

  console.log('after');`

Console shows me 2 logs: before & after

Comment: Ok, try to run the findOne inside the callback of the newuser.save, and report back :)

Comment: Do you mean this?  `newuser.save(function (err) {
   if (err) console.log(err);
   // saved!
   console.log('before');
   user.findOne({'email':'abc@gmail.com'}, function(err, data){
    console.log('here');
    console.log(data);
    console.log(err);
   });
   console.log('after');
  });
`
There's no log on console.

Comment: Try without specifying the email, just `user.findOne`

Comment: No log ('before', 'after') shows even though I changed {'email':'abc@gmail.com'} to {}  `newuser.save(function (err) {
   if (err) console.log(err);
   // saved!
   console.log('before');
   user.findOne({}, function(err, data){
    console.log('here');
    console.log(data);
    console.log(err);
   });
   console.log('after');
  });`

Comment: callback of save() function isn't called if there's no error...

Comment: Thank you very much. I found the problem. Best wishes!

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I understood the problem. NodeJS works asynchronously;  it doesn't wait for long time-consuming processes. So, in my code, if I'm careless when issuing the `mongoose.disconnect` command, some tasks can't finish their work. Just putting that command in the last callback of my work (findOne function callback), made everything work.

```
newuser.save(function (err, doc) {
        console.log('nothing');
        if (err) console.log(err);
        user.findOne({'email':'abc@gmail.com'}, function(err, data){
            console.log('here');
            console.log(data);
            console.log(err);
            mongoose.disconnect();
        });
        // saved!

    });
```

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to move findOne function in the save callback if no err.
Or add a parameter 'callback' to addUser, call it in save callback and call addUser with a function that contains your findOne.

Comment: Thank you. I found the problem and posted a reply :)